# Getting parsing error in xpath expression xsoup

Tags: java, html, xpath, jsoup, xsoup

I am trying to get html elements in result based on text search.

```
   System.out.println(Xsoup.compile("//*[a/text()='bluetooth']").evaluate(document).get());
```

But i am getting below given error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query '*[a/text()='bluetooth']': unexpected token at 'a/text()='bluetooth''
```

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that your xpath query is not valid. What are you trying to extract? A link whose text is "bluetooth"?

Comment: actually, that is a valid XPath expression, but seems like xsoup only supports subset of XPath 1.0 : https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup#syntax-supported

Comment: @har07 Thanks. So you meant xpath expression is valid, but xsoup doesnt support it. Do we have any other library which allows us to search based on text ?

Comment: do you need to use XPath for any specific reason? What about CSS selectors and regular JSoup?

Comment: The OP may be in a similar scenario as me. I need to traverse back up the parent in order to get a specific div based on text. This means that css will not work and I have to use XPath (think about select a table row's second cell based on the first cell containing text)